# Angular JWT package not validating my tokens correctly

Tags: angular, jwt, angular7

So I am using angular 7 and the @auth0/angular-jwt package. I have an auth guard on certain routes where I check to see if the jwt token is expired. No matter what I do, this method is always saying the token is expired. I know the tokens are valid because they are working postman. Anyone have experience with this isTokenExpired method?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

private jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService()



// ...
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');


// Check whether the token is expired and return
// true or false
return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);

  }
}
```

Comment: lol thers a package for that :o :D thats just some base64 encoding its probably quicker to write the script than search for the package

Comment: What are you using to create the token?

Comment: have you checked wether there actually was a token in the localstorage ?

Comment: part of the isTokenExpired function : `if (token === null || token === '') {
        return true;
    }`

Comment: @BrandonMiller I am using the jwt.sign() on my node backend

Comment: @jonathanHeindl I have a console.log on there and yes I am always getting the token out of local storage. Is it supposed to be formatted a certain way? I only have the token, not the JWT before it.

Comment: @matt can you show what you're setting as the exp on the backend? If you're using 'expiresIn', remember that it has to be passed as an object, like so { expiresIn : '1h' }.

Comment: @BrandonMiller ahh that was it! Stupid me thought it was setting some expiration by default... thanks a ton!

Comment: @matt glad I could help! Remember to mark this as answered so it can better help other users in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show what you're setting as the exp on the backend?

If you're using 'expiresIn', remember that it has to be passed as an object, like so:

```
{ expiresIn : '1h' }
```